# Angular 2.0 RC 1 injecting services

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am injecting service into service...by all documentation it should work, but it doesn't.

I have this in main.ts:

```
import { LocalStorageService } from './services/app.localStorage.service';
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, LoginService, ConfigService, LocalStorageService ] );
```

So just the regular stuff, this LocalStorageService should be visible at the app level. Of course, it has @Injectable() on it.

Now in an another service, LoginService, I am trying to use it like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import {LocalStorageService} from '../service/app.localStorage.service';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService
{
    constructor ( private _localStorage : LocalStorageService )
    {
        // Here IT WORKS!
        var val = this._localStorage.read( 'SomeKey' );
    }

    someMethod() : boolean
    {
         // Here IT DOES NOT WORK!
        var val = this._localStorage.read( 'SomeKey' );

        return true;
    }
}
```

This is really strange, it is as if _localStorage in the constructor is local to that method only, not the class, but it shouldn't be.
The error is: "this._localStorage is undefined".

Thank you.

**SOLVED:**

Here's the example, it works: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YU6VqefnUxMmrR0HhhfH?p=preview)

Comment: How do you call `someMerhod`? I'm pretty sure in your case the `this` within `someMethod` isn't instance of `LoginService`

Comment: Of course it is not, as it returns "this._localStorage is undefined"....so that is the question, why?

Comment: Of course this should work, it's common practice. I doubt we can help you without more code.

Comment: Please add some code where you're calling method `someMerhod`

Comment: Is it possible it is because of how "this" works? What if you change the someMethod to an arrow function so "this" will be the instance?

Comment: Let me try to make a plunker example out of this, thanks.

Comment: I have created plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/YU6VqefnUxMmrR0HhhfH?p=preview  It actually works, so something wrong with my code as there is a lot more stuff there than in the plunker example, I need to review it.  The example just loads the app/main, the bootstrapper there adds these 2 services as providers, then it executes app.component that then navigates to the dashboard component, which in turn calls two methods in the injected LoginService: method1() and method2(), out of which method2() calls it's injected LocalStorageService.  I am using FF and Console view to see the messages.

Answer (score 1):

As @yurzui mentioned in his first comment, the likely problem is that when you call `someMethod()` your are not maintaining the proper `this` context of the component.

E.g., you might have some code like this:

```
this.someService.getSomeObservable().subscribe(this.someMethod);  // wrong this context
```

which needs to be rewritten as

```
this.someService.getSomeObservable().subscribe(_ => this.someMethod);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does adding in:

```
@Component({
    providers: [LocalStorageService]
})
```

above the class work?

Comment: No, it does not...and from what I understand, it shouldn't, since this is the service, not a component. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

change `private _localStorage : LocalStorageService` to `public _localStorage : LocalStorageService` ; otherwise `_localStorage` will only be visible in the constructor

Comment: No, it does not work, I tried it. And besides, private means private in the scope of the class, as far as I know. Thank you.

Comment: definitely no, you need it to be public or assign it to a member of your class as in: `this.localService = _localService` and the use `this.localService` in the rest of your class. I urge you to test again because the issue seems quite clear.

Comment: @ManuValdés, see [Parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties) in the TypeScript handbook.  It is perfectly fine to use `private` here.